# How to create custom model Manager that returns users based on group membership

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that is fairly simple. It defines Persons as follow:

```py
class ActiveTAsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

class Person(AbstractUser):
    company_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)

    objects = models.Manager()
    active_TAs = ActiveTAsManager()
```

the custom model manager works well but I want to add a condition based on group membership.

```py
class ActiveTAsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        phds = Group.objects.get(name="phds")
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

This fails because the Group class is not imported.

My question is twofold:

- how can I import the Group class?
- How can I write the filter so it filters based on group membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to import the **`Group`** model here,

```
Person.objects.filter(groups__name='phds')
```

For example:

```
class ActiveTAsManager(models.Manager):
    def phd_users(self):
        return super(models.Manager, self) \
            .get_queryset() \
            .filter(groups__name='phds')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
```

and this can be called as,

```
Person.active_TAs.phd_users()
```